# Electric current in mic

Tags: current, current-measurement, microphone

For a typical mic a singer uses in a concert, how much current is generated when the singer sings? The current transmitted from the diaphragm into the wire.

What does the following specification tell us about the value I am looking for, for example?

[image]

Comment: Most microphones don't work like that. There's an amplifier inside the microphone as the actual current in the microphone's diaphragm is quite small, that small current is across a high impedance and that results in a voltage that is amplified.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie:  Sounds like an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'd reckon there's an amplifier in the microphone. Coming to the point about that small current across a high impedance, is work done in amplifying the voltage? Could you pleas explain the mechanism? Pardon me, I have forgotten a lot of my physics.

Comment: by the way, if you want 32-bit noise floors in 40KHz music, you need 2,500 watts out of the transducer. For 24-bit noise floors in 50KHz music, you only need about 40 milliWatts from the transducer.

Answer (score 4):

All mics work by converting energy in a tiny vibrating diaphragm to electricity. There are two common ways that this is done. In a [dynamic mic](https://www.neumann.com/homestudio/en/what-is-a-dynamic-microphone) the most common type works like a loudspeaker in reverse (in fact you can use a LS as a poor quality mic, it works). Here the mic inpedance itself is typically around 200R, and it is designed to work into an impedance of about 2k. The actual sensitivity varies a lot, but under "normal" conditions we might see a voltage of around 5mV across the mic. This means that it is generating a current in the order of 2.5uA.

The other common type of mic is a [capacitor (condenser) mic](https://www.neumann.com/homestudio/en/what-is-a-condenser-microphone). There are various types but in these the diaphragm (which is part of a charged capacitor) is connected to a FET preamp in the mic itself. Not sure what the current would be for these (I expect it varies quite a lot with diaphragm size and so on) but anyway you never see that current at the XLR connector on the mic body. What you see there is the preamp output, which is designed to be of similar magnitude to a dynamic mic, so that it can use the same preamp (which is now perhaps better described as a secondary preamp).

The mic in your question is a condenser mic by the way. It quotes 33mV/Pa. According to [this chart](https://www.thermaxxjackets.com/sound-pressure-math/), 2Pa is the sound of a jackhammer (they don't say from how close, but loud!) - so 1Pa is still going loud - louder than most singers, except maybe that guy in ACDC. So I would think that our 5mV figure is in the right ballpark here, or perhaps slightly on the low side. (As there is really no "standard vocalist" you are not going to get a precise answer anyway.)

Comment: "there is really no standard vocalist" -> honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if there's an ISO standard for that. They have a standard cup of tea for goodness' sake!

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed reply. I need some time to synthesize it.

Answer (score 0):

> The current transmitted from the diaphragm into the wire.

No, it isn't. This kind of microphone has an internal amplifier in addition to the diaphragm.

This amplifier operates from  the DC "phantom power" provided by the mixing console (48 VDC @ 2 mA), and converts some of that to an AC current/voltage on the wire.

In this case, the rated load impedance is 1000Ω and the output voltage is given as 33 mV/Pa, so the output current would be 33 mV / 1000Ω = 33 µA/Pa.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, Dave! Yes, pretty much that's what I'm looking at. Oh, I was too fast; I didn't mean current transmitted from the diaphragm to the wire; I meant energy conversion. And oh, so this also answers my question on your reply above. Work is indeed done in the amplification. But in the absence of the amplifier, how much current can a typical microphone produce when it's diaphragm is receiving sound waves from a typical vocalist?

Comment: For a condenser element, basically zero, it is generally loaded by a fet gate and at least 1 Giga ohm of resistor! Voltage level? Maybe 10mV or so, but into the 1 Gig (sometimes 10 Gig) || 10pF (Fet gate), that is not a lot. Of course the output of the built in preamp is another story... The dynamic elements do a bit better generally having lower outputs, but at a MUCH lower impedance, so more current (and power) is available.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity's sake, I'll focus on the dynamic microphone.

The voltage source in a dynamic microphone has a high internal resistance - typically on the order of a kOhm. And also, the dynamic microphone is a *transducer*. This means that the electrical load impedance is **transduced** into acoustic impedance. The harder you load such a microphone on its electrical side, the more insensitive it becomes to sound pressure on its acoustic side. The diaphragm stiffens up!

Thus, the idea is to provide a negligible load impedance, by integrating a preamplifier into the microphone assembly. Such a preamplifier will have a bias+offset DC input current in the nA-fA range, and without much measurable effect on the acoustic impedance. This current can also be largely trimmed out. More The more significant will be the input capacitance, along with any parasitic capacitances. For 1kOhm source impedance, a 4.7nF load capacitance provides a 30+kHz low-pass cut-off point, but due to transduction it will add excessive phase shift potentially down to 10kHz. So, 100pF-1nF would be the upper limit on the load capacitance.

A 1nF load is about 16kOhm of impedance at 10kHz. A good starting assumption would be that the loudest human voice will produce about 1mV RMS output from a dynamic microphone transducer. 1mVRMS / 16kOhm is about 60nA of RMS current. I'd say that's the highest current anyone would expect to see out of a dynamic microphone transducer when coupled directly to a preamplifier, with said preamplifier having an input RF filter that looks like 1nF capacitance.

Most built-in preamps will present a much lower capacitive load than 1nF. I'd expect realistic currents in well designed circuits to be at most 1nA through the transducer coil, throughout the audio range and viable input sound pressure.

Just measuring such low AC currents at audio frequencies is challenging - you'd have to design an in-line current transducer circuit with parasitic loading much lower than that presented by the preamplifier itself. So it may not be the easiest thing to *confirm* such currents while being sure that they are not largely affected by the very act of measuring them. Quiet speech into a dynamic microphone, just above the preamp noise would be pushing picoamps into the preamp.

Now suppose that for maximum power transfer we load said 1kOhm dynamic microphone element directly with a 1kOhm resistor. At 1mV open-circuit RMS output voltage, we'd get 0.5uA of current, and 0.5nW of power.

So, as a rough order of magnitude, a dynamic microphone in the employ of a powerful singer, loaded for optimal power transfer, will produce about 1nW of electrical power. Due to transduction losses - mostly in the diaphragm - and acoustic impedance mismatch, I'd expect the acoustic power incident on the diaphragm to be about an order of magnitude larger - so 10nW. Actual values would depend on the circumstances and could easily swing an order of magnitude either way.

For comparison purposes, a good vocalist is limited to producing **about 1 Watt of peak acoustic power**. A sustainable average power is an order of magnitude lower. Unless it's a rock singer we're talking about, perhaps.

A dynamic microphone would capture between a millionth to to a billionth of that power, with lower end being more typical I'd assume.

I have not done any measurements, but probably could whip something up and see what sort of electrical power I could get out of a dynamic microphone when fed a by a well rested professional soprano, say.